# Dependency Injections are undefined in controller functions while using Angular1+ ES6, with controller as a class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I am using ES6 class to define my controller so this is the syntax,

```
export class SearchBarController {
    constructor($log) {
        'ngInject';

        $log.debug("Hello");
    }

    textTyped($log){

        $log.debug("change fired.");
    }
}
```

view :

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="vm.txt" data-ng-change="vm.textTyped()"/>
```

So "Hello" from within the constructor is getting logged fine. But, "change fired" within the typedText() function is not firing because apparently is undefined how do I make my class function textTyped() to access the $log service?

**Note** : If I assign $log to a class property in the constructor like,

```
this.logger = $log;
```

And then do,

```
this.logger.debug("Change fired.");
```

this works. But I am unsure if it's the right approach.

**Update**: Also, this approach exposes this reference to the $log service to the view bound to this controller. Is this harmful?

Is there a better solution?

Comment: `this.logger = $log` is the [recommended approach](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/es6/2015/01/23/exploring-angular-1.3-using-es6.html).

Comment: ok thanks. But wouldn't adding it to 'this' expose it directly to the viewModel/$scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone's interested I found a more elegant solution to the problem using ES6 Object Destructuring :

```
class ABCController {
    constructor($log, $http){
        let vm = this;
        vm.DI = () => ({$log, $http});
    }

    classFn(){
        let vm = this;
        let {$log, $http} = vm.DI();
        //Now use $log and $http straightway

        $log.debug("Testing");
        $http({...}).then();
    }

    classFn2(){
        let vm = this;
        //you can also destructure only the required dependencies in this way
        let {$http} = vm.DI();
    }
}
ABCController.$inject = ['$log', '$http'];
```

In this way you don't need to write ugly/confusing code like vm.DI.log, etc.
Also, in this way the DIs are less exposed in the view.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.logger = $log;
```

As you pointed out, is the way. 
Since it's an object, there is no global scope.

Comment: But wouldn't adding it to 'this' expose it directly to the viewModel/$scope?

Answer (score 2):

```
class SearchBarController {
    constructor($scope, $log) {
        this.log = $log;

        // Scope method
        $scope.vm = this;
    }

    textTyped(){
        this.log.debug("change fired.");
    }
}

SearchBarController.$inject = ['$scope', '$log'];
```

Try like this

Comment: this approach exposes this reference to the $log service to the view bound to this controller. Is this harmful?
I can simply in the view do {{ controllerAs.log.debug("Abc") }}. It's ok with log but what if some other more critical service get's exposed like this?