# While Using ngMap module es6 class in angularjs, 'this' is not binded to the constructor when 'places-auto-complete' is used

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6, ng-map

I'm using AngularJS with ES6, while implementing [ngMap](https://ngmap.github.io/#/!places-auto-complete.html) module for the autocomplete feature of google map.

```
/* html file */
  Enter an address: <br/>
<input places-auto-complete size=80
       ng-model="$ctrl.address"
       component-restrictions="{country:'in'}"
       on-place-changed="$ctrl.placeChanged()"/> <br/>
<div ng-show="$ctrl.place">
  Address = {{$ctrl.place.formatted_address}} <br/>
  Location: {{$ctrl.place.geometry.location}}<br/>
</div>
address : {{$ctrl.address}}
<ng-map></ng-map>
```

And the javascript file containing component

```
'use strict';
(function() {

class RateRestaurantsController {
constructor(NgMap) {
  this.NgMap = NgMap;
  this.types = "";
  this.place = "";
  this.address = "";
  this.map = {};


}

$onInit() {

  this.NgMap.getMap().then((map)=> {
    this.map = map;
  });
}

placeChanged(){
 console.log(this); // This refers the [Object] returned by google map api; not to the the constructor(as shown in the image)
  this.place = this.getPlace();
  this.map.setCenter(this.place.geometry.location);

  }

 }

angular.module('gmHotelRatingApp.rateRestaurants')
.component('rateRestaurants', {
  templateUrl: 'app/rate-restaurants/rate.restaurants.html',
  controller: RateRestaurantsController
});

})();
```

The Object returned which is returned: 
[Image showing 'this' context; which is causing 'this.map' to be undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1bVy.png)

I want '*this.map*' and '*this.place*' reference to constructor property and '*this.getPlaced()*' to fetch the auto complete data. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency Injections are undefined in controller functions while using Angular1+ ES6, with controller as a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36252674/dependency-injections-are-undefined-in-controller-functions-while-using-angular1)

Answer (score 2):

My solution is:

```
constructor(NgMap) {

  this.ngMap = NgMap;

  var controller = this;
  this.ngMap.getMap().then((map) => {
      this.map = map;
  });

  this.myCallback = function () {
     controller.place = this.getPlace();
     controller.map.setCenter(controller.place.geometry.location);
  }


}
```

I know that a function must be outside the constructor but it works for me.

Comment: Works also for me